# Can I apply a WPF style to an element only in a certain layout?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a `TextBlock` style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="FormLabel">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

I use it in `Grid` based forms, e.g:

```
<TextBlock Text="Code" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}" />
```

Now instead of repeating the style name on every `TextBlock` in the grid, I would prefer to e.g. have a `Grid` style like:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="FormGrid">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Then I would, if possible, like to modify my `TextBlock` style to only apply to that element when it is a child element of a `Grid` with style `FormGrid`.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You may have a default TextBlock Style (without x:Key) in the Resources of the Grid.

Comment: @Clemens That is exactly what I said I don't want. I want a style only for textboxes in a `FormGrid`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed possible by using an implicit style within another style as a resource. Take this example:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FormGrid" TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource FormGrid}">
        <TextBlock Text="This text block is styled with FormGrid TextBlock implicit style."/>
    </Grid>        
    <TextBlock Text="This text block uses the default style."/>
</StackPanel>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by out of the box WPF abilities. What you are looking here is CSS like style selectors. WPF Only allows style inheritance through `BasedOn` property. I am not sure if this could be an alternative, but you can define that specific TextBlock style as part of that grid resources and target to match any textblock inside of it.

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
   </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I would have to include that style in each grid. Thanks for the idea, but Yarick has what looks to be my ideal solution.

Comment: Yes, that one is way better!